# How can I acces a JSON array on localhost with Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, localhost, nsurlsession

I need to access a simple array that contains 5 elements and put them in label variables, but it's on my localhost. I read somewhere that I need to put in my router's IP so i did that: http://localhost:8888/credits/credits.json

But my code doesn't work while I have tried several tutorials and options, it doesn't even print and I don't get errors. I just need to put the values from the array in the labels.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewControllerCredits: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var version: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var developers: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var company: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contact: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var disclaimer: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
}

func getData(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.178.1:8888/credits/credits.json")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL){(data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

            for dictionary in json as! [[String: Any]]{
                print(dictionary["developers"])
            }

            print(json)




        }catch let jsonError{
            print(jsonError)
        }
    }.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: JSONSerialization returns an object of type `Any` (`AnyObject` in Swift 2). Now you have to cast it to its correct format, an array or a dictionary. Then you iterate over your array or subscript your dictionary - or both - and get your values.

Comment: Thank you, i understand that now and have added that. But it still won't print anything or give me errors so i don't know whats wrong

Comment: Then please [edit] your question, and add what you've tried and show what didn't work, we'll help further.

Comment: Does your browser print the json if you enter the url? http://192.168.178.1:8888/credits/credits.json if not try: http://localhost:8080/credits/credits.json

Comment: I edited the new code, and tried to enter 192.168.178.1:8888/credits/credits.json which didn't work. http://localhost:8888/credits/credits.json does work but still nothing, no print no errors

Comment: Open Safari.app and try to put the URL. It should help you to identify which one to use. If it works, do you have any message in console about App Transport Security? When you says it doesn't print, is it because data is empty? Does your code goes either in the "if error", "do" "catch"?

Comment: I used the working link, stille no massage. Even if i put: print("test") in the viewDidLoad function, i doesnt print (while it does execute other functions). So i guess i changed something with the console on accident maybe? Cant find anything about it.

Comment: You will get error message after some time. It's take time. i got response

Comment: If it doesn't print even in `viewDidLoad()` that maybe another issue. Could you check that `getData()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Normally URLSession it will take request time. In your code there is no issue. It working fine in my end . My suggestion is use Alamofire for API call.

if a long-running task is not sending or receiving enough data over a period of time, it may be cancelled to be resumed later. Therefore, it is important to make a transfer resumable, if possible.

```
  Alamofire.request("http://192.168.178.1:8888/credits/credits.json").responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's right request time is never the same. It's depends